# Decorator factory for method and property

Tags: typescript

I have two log Decorator functions - one for methods and one for properties (implementation is not important here). Since a method decorator has three parameters and a property decorator only has two, I was wondering if it's was possible to create a single decorator factory which returns the correct decorator function (so you can simply call `@log` instead of `@logProperty` or `@logMethod`):

```
function logMethod(target: any, methodKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
}
function logProperty(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
}

function log(...args) {
    switch(args.length) {
        case 2:
            return logProperty.apply(this, args);
        case 3:
            return logMethod.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Sadly, this is not working, the compiled code uses `__decorate` and calls log with three parameters even for the property decorator (with `undefined` as the last parameter) - I know I can work around the issue by checking if the third argument is `undefined` - but I'm trying to understand why typescript compiles down to that.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKZQBZwCYBk4DmAIqhHAE4CGUFAFFJeQegFyKVgCeANCultgDSqTmwDOUcjDAFe2VGIhSADjXJsACuTjLU5KJxKKVagJSbtu-YYVKYqiogDeAKETvE5dCHJJ5x%20zUAbhcAXxcXUEhYBERlSz0DfGJSCmo6BiZWdi5eeJ1EzmFRRAkpGVNnNw8yMAlEAGsRRABeRAADAH0AEid8qwNi0PaQ6vco6HgkZihaStcPRcRasTgAG1QAOjXCWnaAcWzezBgxAG0mzgBdYdMQpY8vKB8kE-PLq-uPcLHECZikGJ0LQAG6UNZsDicea-RYrdZbHYEPYAZWy62wiDBaxAqDYxwwpwuIhuvDAqAA7ljwfinNjbl8Hm9iddWtS1ozED9FgB5ABGACtSFBNvJgNJUFoCtZ6IwZnkEtZirwFg9EPLYR4gVBuJr3LVxQQfJQ%20Rs2JJcbq1YhUGAQGgqKa8YgLagrd9TGEIv8pogkbRNoG5WIYYsxBSYFAIBhaMHtraCJhQ2qIJQgYgAEwsPVLJ4vOKKpKEEhkKhqTaUZTKNaceiEsS8YN3HOp9MAZmz1sWMGA9E4ujgwHYTHOGaurRabQARHbkHy9FPk12lgB6Feeby%20OKMShoKB6ZIltLlyvV2tvRsj5vL9zhG8b55bvcCQ%20pMsUCtVmt106XgghzlFjFSgQDWKBOxvTBtCpckqQAUXIbRyFoKcADk4Cgdh2RgTFZ3nchEEHbcqGQfdyDERdRkWcIfggNY0zETwOGwOBkAAYXosRGNVdwAAEkV%20ZBOAAMXACA5iqa14Q2bZdinIS-jEgBCSjfm5Dx%20MIX4ZhQTgeUwPQUUkaRkSXXNN1eetNiEozygITl1L4gTFniGAwX3XTbJM8RjJkEJQiAA)

Thanks!

Comment: Adding overloads to the `log` function removes the errors when using the decorator, but there are other problems. I have to look at this more. https://tsplay.dev/wj5JYW

Comment: Do you have an example of a property decorator `@logProperty` that works when applied directly?  I don't think `get` and `set` work for this.  I see changes when overriding `initializer` but not `get` and `set`.

Comment: As already mentioned, overload the function declaration or use an optional parameter. The purpose of using a decorator factory instead of a simple decorator is to allow passing parameters which may indeed result in a different generator being returned by the factory depending on the configuration

Comment: @LindaPaiste - thanks for the overload tip - didn't think about that, I didn't quite understand your second comment about a `@logProperty` which works directly, do you mean when setting on a getter\setter?

Comment: @Moshezauros if I use your @propertyLogDecorator on a property it does not seem to work.  I played with this a bit and I have a @methodDecorator that actually logs method calls.  I cannot do the same for properties and after looking at the TS docs I think it might not be possible.  I think you can decorate an accessor (`@log get myOtherString() {` but not a property `@log private myString: string; }`.  Like you can apply a decorator function to the property but it doesn't *do anything*.

Comment: "NOTE  A Property Descriptor is not provided as an argument to a property decorator due to how property decorators are initialized in TypeScript. This is because there is currently no mechanism to describe an instance property when defining members of a prototype, and no way to observe or modify the initializer for a property. The return value is ignored too. As such, a property decorator can only be used to observe that a property of a specific name has been declared for a class." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators

Comment: @LindaPaiste - here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/log-property-decorator?file=index.ts

Comment: @Moshezauros Thanks for sharing that!  I swear I tried something very similar and it just didn't work for me.  I'll have to look at this closer tomorrow and see why I couldn't get it.  https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-method-decorators-jn3ug

Comment: with pleasure, and thanks for you help!